# Is there a way to get HTML text through python and a web browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a website for work and I need to go through a list of numbers and determine if the user associated with the number is still active. The website requires a sign in so I can't use requests. Is there a way I can run it through my chrome browser to get the information I require?
If I can get the HTML then I am fine from there onward with the code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: According to the following article, you can use requests to log into a website: http://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/.

Comment: the `selenium` package is a common go-to tool for web automation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can I have the webpage you are trying to access?